# PowerShell Parameters default values

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a basic function:

```
Function Write-AdvancedLog{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        $WriteToEtl,
        $Message,
        $CurrentFunction
    )
}
```

Essentially I want to specify a parameter `-WriteToEtl` without specifying a value. If the parameter is added to the Function call (`Write-AdvancedLog -WriteToEtl`) it will do a certain thing, if the switch isn't specified, it won't.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `[switch]$WriteToEtl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `switch` data-type just for that. You can specify this using `[switch]$WriteToEtl`

Good resource: http://sinairv.github.io/blog/2015/05/18/powershell-the-switch-data-type/